# Finding probability that the number is 30

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Okay I found this one on a test and I am still struggling to solve this so here it goes: A bag contains $50$ tickets numbered $1,2,3,4......50$ of which five are drawn at random and arranged in ascending order of magnitude $(x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4<x_5)$. Find the probability that $x_3=30$.

Comment: Try the hypergeometric distribution .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total number of ways to choose $5$ out of $50$ tickets is:

$$\binom{50}{5}=2118760$$

---

The number of ways to choose those tickets with the smallest two being between $1-29$, the middle one being $30$, and the largest two being between $31-50$ is:

$$\binom{29-1+1}{2}\cdot\binom{50-31+1}{2}=77140$$

---

Hence the probability is:

$$\frac{77140}{2118760}\approx3.641\%$$